# Questions on Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

I've been evaluating different options for my iOS app's back-end data storage and have come across Parse.com. The app entails taking a photo on the iPhone and then uploading the photo along with some other data (simple end-user inputs) to a service where the photo is then processed (more on that in a bit), a response is given to the client, and all of the data originally sent (including the photo) is stored for future retrieval.

The "processing" part is currently a Matlab algorithm that essentially analyzes the image pixel-by-pixel and then outputs a value.

The question is, does Parse.com offer the capability to process data on the server after the request is received and then respond to the client with a message based on the result of the processing step. If so, is it possible to integrate a compiled dll into this processing step?

OR...

Should I create a service outside of Parse that handles the incoming request, image processing, and response to the client, and then use Parse for just the data storage?

Very new to Parse so any suggestions on other things I should consider would also be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to have your own server on which your matlab algorithm will run. Parse server can access it via http request (you can find it in the documentation on how to execute http requests from parse).

Comment: From the point that I have to host anything, then wouldn't it just make more sense that my own hosted service be the primary request handler for my iOS app? Eg. request workflow: App -> My Service w/Matlab code -> Parse for Storage (async call) -> Response. Rather than App -> Parse -> My Service (synchronous call) -> Parse -> Response.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some processing on Parse.com using Cloud code
https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#cloud_code

In your case, you probably need to write a cloud function:
https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions

You would need to port your current algorithm to Javascript, though.